# How to find isometry and functions for the given cartesian equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, isometry, cartesian-closed-categories

[Catesian question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whzZS.png)

I am unable to proceed on how to do the steps, if someone can guide me , im not looking for full solution but some guidance.

Question :
Denote by
a,b
the lines with the Cartesian equations
y=0,x=0
respectively, and
i=[
1
0
​
],j=[
0
1
​
]
(a) Find the functions
f(x,y)
and
g(x,y)
such that
γ
a,i
​
(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))
. (b) If
γ
a,i
​
(P)=Q
, show that the midpoint of the segment
PQ
belongs to
a
. (c) What is the isometry
γ
a,i
​
γ
b,j
​

?

Comment: Which book reference?

Comment: @Narasimham , is it possible to help out.